# How to display Logo Image for google job posting

Tags: azure-blob-storage, google-search-api, google-crawlers, google-search-console

I have implemented the code on job details page which have script reading the job for posting onto google search.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    "baseSalary":{
    "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
    "value": "  &#xA3;10,000 - &#xA3;20,000",
    "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "datePosted":"2019-03-14",
    "description":"&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Design and developing of laboratory under their respective department/ section.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Student assessment, evaluation and work related to BTE exam .&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Developing resource materials and assisting in curriculum development&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Work on industrial problems and projects and assisting in extension services to the community&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Coordinating education related activities.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Co-curricular and extra-curricular activities.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Assisting in department administration.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Student counseling.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;bull; Any other duties/work assigned from time to time Profile Summary&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;EmploymentType:Full Time&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Eligibility:Any Graduate&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Role:Lecturer/Professor,Special EducationTeaching&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Industry:Educational/Training&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Salary:7 Lacs Function:Teaching/Education&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Experience:6 - 10 Years&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;",
    "employmentType":"Full Time",
    "hiringOrganization": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Surat Recruiters",
    "logo": "https://markallendevelopment.blob.core.windows.net/iris/Admin/upload/d00bb99c-34bf-4e2a-881b-009318b74bfb.jpg",
    "sameAs":"http://xitstaging-001-site6.mysitepanel.net/employer/surat-recruiters/889435f4-462d-4f7e-8edb-abd2f1383f4d"
    },
    "jobLocation": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Ring Road",
    "addressRegion": "Surat",
    "postalCode": "395001",
    "streetAddress": "220, 2nd Floor, Multistoried building"
    },
    "description":"Surat Gujarat"
    },
    "salaryCurrency": "EUR",
    "title": "Surat Health Jobs in Physiotherapy",
    "validThrough":"2019-04-12"
    }
</script>
```

My job gets display within Google Search Jobs Explorer, but the logo is not displayed.Instead the First letter of the Job Title is being displayed onto google. I reviewed various documents as well as googled a lot to understand why the image isn't been displayed, although I didn't got any  solution yet.
I had around 1.5 Yrs old articles (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting) stating that its a common issue faced with google jobs, but I want the recruiter company logo at any cost, if url exists on Azure Image Blob.

I tried replacing logo url of Azure Image Blob with the one at local domain based url path for getting job logo into google search explore but that too didn't worked.

Can any one help me at the earliest to resolve this, as its been a long time I am searching for the solution and need to deliver within this week to my client.

**References**
Job Posting Document Link : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting

Comment: its a valid question, can any one answer it?